# Call a function while application closed through task manager

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my windows application I have a Close button. While click on this it will call a function .

```
private void btClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  EndFormalities();
}
```

Is it possible to call the  EndFormalities() function, while closing this application through Task manager . Any predefined Events available in Windows.NET ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the WM_CLOSE message. Once you receive it, you can call your EndFormalities() method. Look at this answer on how to catch it: [Handle WM_CLOSE message send to C# Tray App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826197/handle-wm-close-message-send-to-c-sharp-tray-app)
Also read this one: [Can I handle the killing of my windows process through the Task Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527450/can-i-handle-the-killing-of-my-windows-process-through-the-task-manager)

Comment: I've tried with "override void WndProc" . But its not even triggered while Ending the application process through Task manager.