# How to handle WM_CLOSE in NotifyIcon based WPF app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF app that runs in the System Tray. It is based on the NotifyIcon project (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon).

I need to get it to respond to the WM_CLOSE command that is issued by the `taskkill /IM` command (that is run from the command line).

Does anyone know what method I need in my app to respond to WM_CLOSE ?

UPDATE

I should have made clear, for a system tray app, there might not be a window present.

I tried adding `onClosing` to the Window object. However if I issue `taskkill /IM ...` it only gets fired if the window is open.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
```

So I guess I need something on the application. For the application, I have tried overriding `OnExit` and the `Exit` event - but neither got triggered.

Comment: Try this https://pingfu.net/csharp/2015/04/22/receive-wndproc-messages-in-wpf.html

Comment: @Michael thanks for the suggestions - I have tried your suggestions but no luck - see updated question.

Comment: @M312V thanks for the suggestions - I have tried your suggestions but no luck - see updated question.

Comment: You may not need a window, but you certainly need a message loop. That message loop is where you'll receive the `WM_CLOSE` message. Presumably WPF has some idiomatic way of handling messages before they are dispatched, something akin to "PreTranslateMessage" or whatever.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826197/handle-wm-close-message-send-to-c-sharp-tray-app

Comment: There is *always* a window, only way that notifications can work.  But it is well hidden in that project, it is WindowMessageSink.  It is likely to be will hidden from taskkill.exe as well, you'll have to try.  Task Manager used to use WM_CLOSE in the olden days.  It doesn't any more, makes it behave too random.  It now uses TerminateProcess() redrum, high odds that taskkill.exe does as well.

Comment: @spiderplant0 Did you ever find a satisfactory solution?  I am faced with a similar problem try to get a WiX installer to stop a system tray application based on the Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification.dll.  I understand that the WiX installer util:CloseApplication element possibly sends WM_CLOSE, so I would love to know how to catch it.